# How to make sense of this subset question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $$A=\{1,{\{\emptyset}\}\}$$

then is $$B={\{\emptyset}\} \subseteq A?$$

I would say yes it is because it is the set containing the empty set, but the solution says it is not. Why is this?

Comment: Empty set is an element of A so B is an element of A.

Comment: Hi that doesnt really help to clarify for me

Comment: @PersonaA That's good that you found the statement unhelpful -- Empty set is most definitely **not** an element of $A$.

Comment: As a side comment: $B \in A$, but $B \not\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is correct: it is not. In order for $B$ to be a subset of $A$, every element of $B$ must be an element of $A$. What are the elements of $B$? There is only one, $\varnothing$. What are the elements of $A$? $1$ and $\{\varnothing\}$. Neither of these is $\varnothing$, so $\varnothing\notin A$, and therefore $B\nsubseteq A$. Note that $\varnothing$, the element of $B$, and $\{\varnothing\}$, one of the elements of $A$, are *not* the same thing: $\varnothing$ is a set with no members, and $\{\varnothing\}$ is a set with one member, that one member being the set $\varnothing$.

Comment: But B is the set contain the null set right?

Comment: @PersonaA: $B$ is the set whose only element is the null set. But the null set is *not* an element of $A$, so $B$ is not a subset of $A$. (You may be getting confused by the fact that $\varnothing$ is a *subset* of every set; it’s not an *element* of every set, however.)

Comment: @PersonaA: You’re welcome.

Comment: Set theorists make everything a set. So what is are natural numbers in set theory? The usual  definition is  $0=\phi$ and $n+1=n\cup \{n\}$.

Comment: @user254665: Yes, and the set of natural numbers is then $\omega$, whose existence is guaranteed by the axiom of infinity. If one is using that formalism, $A=\{1\}$, and $B=\{0\}=1$.

Comment: I brought this up because we have ,in the answer to the  Q, $\phi \ne 1$  which  depends on what "1" is.